# height 100% behaves strangely when stretching page width

Tags: html, css

attempting to have a body that takes up 100% of the page minus the header and footer. have managed to get that to work, but if I stretch the page width wise, the height and margin-bottom css with % values behave in an unexpected way by either shrinking or expanding. at least to me this doesn't make any sense as the parent has not changed size at all, would greatly appreciate some insight.

example: https://gfycat.com/KeenOnlyKawala

css:

```
.body {
    margin: 0;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.row, .col {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.row {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.col {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.scroll-x {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.scroll-y {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.Header.row {
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
}

.Footer.row {
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.SideBar {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.SideBarButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 55%;
    background-color: black;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.Editor {
    display: inline-block;
}

.RightArrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```

asp.net layout:

```
<body>
<div class="Header row"></div>
<div class="body row">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<div class="Footer row">
</div>
</body>
```

index:

```
<div class="SideBar">

</div>
<div class="SideBarButton">
    <div class="RightArrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="Editor">

</div>
```

Comment: The % values in margin refer to the width of the parent element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: @bags sorry, but I'm not sure how that applies to my issue. the parent (.body) never changes height so when I do height:100% of a child it should be bound by the bounds of .body. why then does the height change when I explicitly change the width? (as I've never explicitly set universal margins, only margin-bottom)

Comment: May I suggest using `100vw` and `100vh` instead? (Google them)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't read your original question carefully enough. Still, the margin-bottom of the `.SideBarButton` is 55%, so as the .body width grows, the bottom margin will. Because vertical-align on both `.SideBar` and `.SideBarButton` are default, the large bottom margin effectively pushes the `.SideBar` lower. The height is actually set correctly, but it is cropped at the bottom due to `.row` having `overflow:hidden` .

In the code below I just set .SideBar to have `vertical-align: top;` I am not sure if this is your desired outcome.

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
}
.row,
.col {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.row {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.col {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.scroll-x {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.scroll-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.Header.row {
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
.Footer.row {
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.SideBar {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.SideBarButton {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 55%;
  background-color: black;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.Editor {
  display: inline-block;
}
.RightArrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Header row"></div>
  <div class="body row">

    <div class="SideBar">

    </div>

    <div class="SideBarButton">
      <div class="RightArrow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="Editor">

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="Footer row">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you, this fixes the issue. still not 100% certain why the margins related to height are scaled with the width but I've got miles to learn (have been avoiding webdev for 5 years).